# Could My Ku-Klux-Rogue Exist?

Tags: biology, creature-design, evolution, mythical-creatures, anatomy

The Ku-Klux-Rogue is a successful gigantic monster species with four heads.
The front head that of a Saber-toothed-tiger, the other front head of a fearsome dragon, a wolf's head protruding from the middle of it's back, and a king cobra for a tail. It also has the body of a coyote, the front legs of a fox, and the hind legs of a yak.The fox claws are retractable. Each head is tied to it's own spinal cord, and it does not breath fire.

This is a hard thing to work on, and my question is: In planet 39, which has  Earth-like biology and environment, could this beast ever evolve? A point to consider is how the snake fits in and why the legs are so different. If so, what species could it have evolved from and what evolutionary pressures led to it?

Note: There's no magic on the planet 39.

Comment: I am thinking best to dispense with the legs and also the mammary glands and instead use extra heads from various animals for those things.  Because heads are most awesome as you understand.

Comment: The legs are needed for moving around.

Comment: Scuzzlebutt did ok with Patrick Duffy for a leg.

Comment: Yeah, but only one leg had Patrick Duffy . The rest did not have heads for legs or arms.

Comment: Hello Monsterous. I hope you'll forgive me, but we've seen a lot of "could my creature exist?" questions lately and a lot of them have been closed. The problem is that you're apparently asking if it can exist here, on Earth, in real life, which it obviously can't, rather than telling us about Planet 39, its rules, and asking us if your creature is consistent with those rules. As such, I've entered a new [question type](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8133/40609) to help users better understand what questions are and are not on-topic for consideration.

Comment: Wtf kinda name is Ku-Klux-Rogue?

Comment: Come on! Can't you realize that the name is based of the Ku-Klux-Klan!?

Comment: Wow, you really struck out with this query!  Honest question: did you actually just ask this question with a straight face? I see you're pretty new here, and I think it would be best for you review the [tour] and [help] and [learn what Worldbuilding is all about](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7859/what-is-the-worldbuilding-site-about).

Answer (score 1):

I doubt such an animal could evolve.
You would have to find some evolutionary advantage to having four distinct heads.
I guess you aren't expecting the dragon head to breath fire, right?

Having a head coming out of the centre of a spine would be quite a feat - really it's a good idea to think about the basic central nervous system - if you've got four heads, then you've got a whole load of sense-organs doing all sorts of things doubly redundantly - and that doesn't seem to make a whole load of sense - because they are all tied to the same spinal cord, any one decapitation kills the lot.

Then there's the problem of how to give birth / reproduce.

How about this instead - the same species, with a huge amount of DNA, which can grow to have any one of said four heads, or be scaled, or be furry, etc - all depending upon environmental factors..

That is far more plausible, and even possible within an earth-like biology - it would have to be one which allows for massive specialisation (large DNA) so far fewer extinction events - but other than that, it would be a possibility, maybe!

Comment: You see, the tiger head does the same purpose a tiger head might do. The dragon head keeps watch for attacks from the side, the goat head eats meat that's too ripe for the lion head, and the snake head keeps watch from behind, just in case.

Comment: Dragon and Snake could be replaced with eyes.  goat and tiger just need to change the digestion system - much easier than four heads!

Comment: Yeah, but eyes don't fight, do they? So there are heads so this way the heads can defend the side and behind.

Comment: Eyes don't need to fight, and heads aren't great fighters either.  Better weapons are found with claws, spiked or clubbed tails - because if they get damaged, it doesn't kill you.

Comment: And you said ''tiger and goat.'' Could you see that the head protruding from the middle of the back is a wolf?

Comment: I think you are convinced it is possible, but as I said, I don't think it is.  The details aren't really important. It wouldn't live long enough to be anything other than sorrow for it's mother. There is nothing more to be said about it.